# How to differentiate manual save and programmatic save in CRM 2011 JScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I have a Javascript code registered `onSave` of record. I need to check whether the save operation is happening by **clicking on Save button** or **saving programmatically** like `Xrm.Page.data.entity.save()`.

Do we have a JScript code to get the source control of the event, means event generator?

Answer (score 1):

Without this information on the context why not set a variable in the JavaScript function where you call entity.save explicitly?  You can then check this from any other JavaScript function to determine "context".  It's a bit of a hacky global flag but it'll do the job.

If you need to get a hold of this "context" within a plugin you can create a hidden attribute on the form setting `submitMode('always')` that you set prior to save within the custom JavaScript and reset on load.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like that: https://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/f/117/t/58773.aspx

Comment: This link is to prevent the form saving. I need to check the event generator. Wanted to know whether saving the form by clicking on Save button or programmatically.
And I tried executionContext and no luck.